# jQuery autocomplete with MySql data using Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, asp-classic, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like to add the jQuery autocomlete feature based on data fetched from MySQL, using Classic ASP and a combination of server-side scripting (VBScript and JavaScript for jQuery).
The problem is $ is not recognised since the jQuery scripting tags are loaded (logically) only after the server-side work is completed.
Is there a way to run the jQuery scripting tags on the server-side? After all jQuery is merely a library?
If not, what would be your solution for an autocomplete feature based on MySQL-stored data?
Thanks!

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source_scripts/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="../source_scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../source_scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <%
    Set c = Server.createObject("adodb.connection"): c.Open "Driver=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;Server=188.121.44.188;UID=admin;PWD=Password;Database=testingDB;Option=3"
    Set r = Server.createObject("adodb.recordset"): r.activeConnection = c
    r.Open "SELECT * FROM testTable"
    do until r.eof
      call addTags(r("Name"),r("Surname"),r("ID"))
      r.movenext
    loop
    call autoSearch()
  %>

  <script language="javascript" runat="server">
    searchTags = new Array;
    function addTags(a,b,c){
      searchTags.push(a + " " +b + "  (" + c + ")");
    }
    function autoSearch(){
      $(function(){
        $("#searchline").autocomplete({
          source: searchTags
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="searchline" type="text">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the server-side script that's used to search for the completion of the word you're typing should reside in another file

Comment: yeah, but that means including a hidden iframe or something, which I would really like to avoid since I'm dealing here with tons of data which would have to pass to the parent frame in one variable.

Comment: The thing to remember about server side is that it means precisely that - the script runs on the server.  The consequence of this is that you can't run it again without reloading the page.  What you're trying to do is change what the page after it has loaded and you need client side script. I suspect that the most elegant solution to this involves AJAX, so I've added the tag

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source_scripts/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="../source_scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../source_scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        <%
        Set c = Server.createObject("adodb.connection"): c.Open "Driver=MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver;Server=188.121.44.188;UID=admin;PWD=Password;Database=testingDB;Option=3"
        Set r = Server.createObject("adodb.recordset"): r.activeConnection = c
        r.Open "SELECT * FROM testTable"
        Response.Write("var searchTags = new Array;" & vbcrlf)
        do until r.eof
            Response.Write("searchTags.push('" & r("Name") & " " & r("Surname") & " (" & r("ID") & ")" & "');" & vbcrlf)
            r.movenext
        loop
        %>
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="searchline" type="text">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#searchline").autocomplete({
                    source: searchTags
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I though about something similar, but that would fill my html page with all this data, which is really a lot, like thousands of "searchTags.push" lines in the view source page, which is something I would like to avoid. Thought about doing that in an iframe, but this would mean needing to pass data to the parent document. Now that I'm thinking about it, also the text line is in the user-side html, so the term $("#searchline") wouldn't work, it would have to be something like $("#searchline", window.parent.document) but that's another issue.

Comment: Yeah. It's not the best solution if there is alot of data probably. Maybe you can try something like this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote?